# Moving directlabels slightly to left

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, graphing, direct-labels

I am trying to move my direct labels just slightly to the left, not one group but all groups. By default dl.move only moves one group at a time.

```
library(directlabels)
library(ggplot2)

count <- c(1,5,6,7,8,8)
year <- c(rep(c(2000,2001,2002),2))
group <- c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3))
c <- data.frame(year,count,group)

p <- ggplot(c, aes(x=year, y=count, colour=group)) + geom_line()

direct.label(p, "first.points")
```

I can move one point with...

```
kif <- dl.move("A", hjust=2, vjust=0)
direct.label(p, list("first.points",kif))
```

but I'd ideally just want to move the whole thing over a by the same hjust. Is there some silly syntax I've totally missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dl.trans(x=x-0.1)` moves everything to the left 0.1cm.

```
direct.label(p, list(dl.trans(x=x-0.1), "first.qp"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew mine was off because the movements weren't proportional.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. A simple

```
direct.label(p, list("first.points",hjust=2, vjust=0))
```

Not perfect but works, the spacing isn't uniform like default.